Identifying the following SMD component "FPR 595" (with top bar and dot)
I need help in identifying a SMD component which has the following marking code "FPR (with top bar and dot) 595" which is a 10 pin component 4 pins to the left and right and 2 pins on the top and bottom and it's present in the power line. Most likely Voltage detector but not sure:

Attaching the schematic for your reference:


Sometime, identifying this type of components are pretty hard, there is a one trick to find it out, in Which electronic component or device this IC has been placed, that help us to guess the IC and it functionality. If you can take a screenshot of the component.

It's a MPS MPM3811GG DC-DC module.


(Source: lcsc.com)

+1 Just a side comment... MPS is known for having a line over the first three/four letters on their chip marking.

Thanks @nanash1 and Colin for your inputs.
